# Method for finding total size of a samba share file, except for JCIFS length()

Tags: java, samba, jcifs

I need to find a set of details about a samba share file using a Java code with JCIFS. Even though getDiskFreeSpace() prints out a value, the "length()", meaning the total size, is printed out as 0 everytime. I need a method which could help me find out this total size.

Does anyone know a similar API I could try or what I should do in order to get printed a value, not 0? 
Snippet from code:

```
try
        {
            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("*****", "username", "password");
            SmbFile smb = new SmbFile("smb://*****/Global/FR/342/WM_GER",auth);
            smb.connect();
            System.out.println("free space : "+smb.getDiskFreeSpace());
            System.out.println("total space : "+smb.length()); // prints 0
            Long percent = (smb.length() - smb.getDiskFreeSpace())/smb.length(); // gives exception because length is 0
            System.out.println("percent : "+percent);

            BigDecimal filesystemUsedSpace = BigDecimal.valueOf(smb.getDiskFreeSpace());
            System.out.println("filesystemUsedSpace "+filesystemUsedSpace);
            System.out.println("smb.getDiskFreeSpace() "+smb.getDiskFreeSpace());
            System.out.println("smb.getContentLength() "+smb.getContentLength());
            System.out.println("smb.getContentLengthLong() "+smb.getContentLengthLong());
            System.out.println("smb.getType() "+smb.getType());
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SmbException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Output ( when the "percent" variable is commented, as it would give an exception, if not due to the 0 value of the length() ):

```
free space : 10354356224
total space : 0
filesystemUsedSpace 1011870294016
smb.getDiskFreeSpace() 1011870294016
smb.getContentLength() 0
smb.getContentLengthLong() -1
smb.getType() 1
```

Comment: I also would like to know this, I have the same problem